# Best choice for robust self hosting server: WCF vs. ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

We currently have an .NET 4 application that consists of Windows Service running in the background and local or remote clients (only 1-3 normally).

The clients have a WPF GUI and need some data from the windows service. Therefore, we use WCF with NamedPipe binding for a local client and NetTcp binding for remote clients. This works, but we often have problems with endpoints that are not reachable (channel faulted or not found etc.). We already try to rebuild faulted connections but it seems to be pretty fragile...

Now enter Web Api: It looks like a HTTP based stack might be more robust (no channels, no endpoints, can be self-hosted in windows service as well). There seems to be no problems with broken channels because each request is handled individually. So if something fails, you just repeat the request. (And we have experience with ASP.NET MVC from other apps, so this not new to us).

Now we are thinking what might be our best bet. Is it better to "harden" our existing WCF service (one service interface with about 15 operations) or to move the interface to Web Api and run it as HTTP requests (with JSON data)? Performance is not our main issue here...

Any ideas?
Hartmut

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you stick with WCF (SOAP) services for your WPF application rather than moving to the Web API. There are a number of reasons for this. First I think we need to consider what the new Web API is trying to address - namely to provide a framework for supporting RESTful/HTTP/hypermedia services. This is likely to be a good fit for building applications that make heavy use of HTTP such as web, mobile and JavaScript applications, where you want to maximise the "reach" or interopability of your services (irrespective of platform). This is not to say that you can't use it for WPF clients but in your case, where all traffic is local to your domain, it makes more sense to stick with your current implementation.

The binding choices you have made for your services / clients sound ok to me. I would focus on why your channels are faulting and address these issues. You may also want to consider hosting your services via IIS and use WAS to expose your non-HTTP endpoints. I have had much success with this in the past and for the most part has been pretty stable. It also takes away a few of the headaches with managing your own host. If you are concerned about the TCP binding faults, then just create a new HTTP or wsHTTP endpoint and use that instead. This will provide you exactly the same transport the web api uses without having to change your programming model.

Comment: Would you mind to update us if still Self-hosted WebAPI is better choice over Self-Hosted WCF please.